Reroofing with TechShield vs plain OSB over existing wood planks - moisture concerns
I have a question about the use of TechShield (OSB with an attached foil radiant barrier) versus using plain OSB in a reroofing project in Southern California.
Due to budget constraints, the TechShield boards are being placed on top of existing wood plank sheathing. The existing planks are structurally sound, but are not in good enough condition to be an effective substrate for the underlayment (Grace Ice & Water Shield) and shingles themselves.
I know that the TechShield foil will be useless as a radiant barrier sandwiched between the planks and the OSB due to the absence of an air gap, but I'm wondering if it's actually worse than just using plain OSB. The manufacturer notes that condensation may form when the exterior is cold and the interior is warm and humid. The foil is perforated, which I assume assists with evaporation when the foil is exposed to the attic air, but would the condensation get trapped when in direct contact with wood on both sides (planks and OSB)? Is it going to pose a greater risk for mold and/or rot, or is condensation not relevant in this configuration?
Similarly, if water happens to penetrate the ice & water shield, will the OSB have a harder time drying out due to the presence of the foil compared to plain OSB, given that in either case it'll be sitting on top of wood planks?
Thank you for any insight you can provide!

